# Php-phantomjs with Laravel (File does not exist or is not executable: bin/phantomjs)

Tags: php, laravel, centos, laravel-5.1, php-phantomjs

I'm trying to use **[php-phantomjs](https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs)** with Laravel 5 under **CentOS 7** and **Windows 8**.

I followed the instructions at **[PHP Phantom installation](http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/#installation)** (installation done with success), after that I received this error while trying to execute the **Basic Usage** code:

**Error when executing PhantomJs procedure "default" - File does not exist or is not executable: bin/phantomjs (View: PATH_TO_PROJECT\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)**

---

**Basic usage code**

```
use JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client;

$client = Client::getInstance();

/** 
 * @see JonnyW\PhantomJs\Message\Request 
 **/
$request = $client->getMessageFactory()->createRequest('http://google.com', 'GET');

/** 
 * @see JonnyW\PhantomJs\Message\Response 
 **/
$response = $client->getMessageFactory()->createResponse();

// Send the request
$client->send($request, $response);

if($response->getStatus() === 200) {

    // Dump the requested page content
    echo $response->getContent();
}
```

I Googled a lot, finding and trying several solutions, but without success. Here on Stackoverflow, I found one question **[Anyone successfully used jonnyw's “php phantomjs” with laravel, in a ubuntu envirement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30766018/anyone-successfully-used-jonnyws-php-phantomjs-with-laravel-in-a-ubuntu-envi)**. I can see in the last comment that the guy solved the problem with:

```
$client->setBinDir('absolute_path/bin');
$client->setPhantomJs('phantomjs.exe');
```

I triyed that also and it's return another error :

**File does not exist or is not executable: phantomjs.exe (View: PATH_TO_PROJECT\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)**

But when I try:

```
echo file_exists('absolute_path/bin/phantomjs.exe');
```

It returns 1 which means PHP can find the file with `absolute_path`.

---

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Anyone already successfully used “php phantomjs” with laravel who can help me?

**NOTE :** The code included in question is a windows version code, but i receive the same error in the both OS.

---

**UPDATE 1**

After changing `absolute_path` to `relative path` it seem like it know `phantomjs.exe` now, but steel raise same error with `phantomloader`:

**File does not exist or is not executable: ../bin/phantomloader (View: PATH_TO_PROJECT\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)**

Tried this solution, but same error :

```
$client->setPhantomLoader('../bin/phantomloader');
```

Comment: have you dumped the auto-load `composer dump-autoload` ?

Comment: Just now and unfortunately there's no changes, same problem :(

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Are you sure you are using Linux binary? Because `phantomjs.exe` is (most likely) Windows executable.

Comment: Thanks for your time @user3584460, Yes i'm sure. I use CentOS 7 & Windows 8 and i receive the same error in the both OS (code in question is windows version) updating my answer.

Comment: Try changing `$client->setPhantomJs('absolute_path/bin/phantomjs.exe');` and do not change `$client->setBinDir('absolute_path/bin');`.

Comment: Unfortunately, same error `File does not exist ...` :(

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki ... make sure the phantomjs file has executable permissions. Also, try adding it to the system PATH variable and then ``$client->setBinDir('');``.

Comment: also add the location of the executable to ``putenv("PATH=/path/to/executable/folder');``

Comment: Ok. What I said doesn't work. Just now checked. Hold on.

Comment: `setPhantomJs` accepts full path which then it passes to private function `validateExecutable` that does `file_exists` and `is_executable`. So, it must be working with the full path. Add a few `echo`s in `Client.php` to see what is happening.

Comment: The problem is is_executable returns a false for phantomloader

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki can you try http://pastebin.com/5sYwQA5T on a linux machine ? (don't forget to change the ``$bin_path`` variable to the bin folder

Comment: also change phantomjs.exe to the linux counterpart

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, have a look at the video here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=unLTKz9Jqyw

This guy explains all the stuff you might need. Hope that helps.

**EDIT**:

Try putting this code...

```
<?php
//test.php

$phantom_loc = "C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\projects\web-optimization\phantomjs4\src\bin\phantomjs.exe";

$dir = "C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\projects\web-optimization\phantomjs4\src\bin\\";

//Is dir executable
$dir_is_Writeable = @file_exists($dir . ".");

if ($dir_is_Writeable === true) {
    echo "$dir is writable";
} else {
    echo "$dir is not writable";
}

echo "<br><br>";
//is executable
if(is_executable($phantom_loc)) {
    echo ("$phantom_loc is executable");
} else {
    echo ("$phantom_loc is not executable");
}

echo "<br><br>";

//Jonnyw
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client;

$client = Client::getInstance();
$client->setBinDir('C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\projects\web-optimization\phantomjs4\src\bin\\');
$client->setPhantomJs('phantomjs.exe');

var_dump($client->getCommand());
```

Comment: Do you have phantomjs.exe in the place? Or did you even install phnatomjs, because I couldn't find it anywhere on the page that you installed PhantomJS. If not, go http://phantomjs.org/download.html and install it now.

Comment: Yes, already mentioned in question "I followed the instructions at PHP Phantom installation (installation done with success)".

Comment: Do you have phantomJS.exe in the same directory? If not try to put it. Because the code is working fine for me.

Comment: I have the phantomJS.exe in /bin directory.

Comment: is phantomloader in the same directory

Comment: Yes i have 3 files in `/bin` directory (phantomjs.exe + phantomloader + phantomloader.bat).

Comment: Check out my edit and give me the output of that file

Comment: if i comment line `var_dump($client->getCommand());` i have `../bin is writable & ../bin/phantomjs.exe is executable` if not i get **File does not exist or is not executable: ../bin/phantomloader**...

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Well as I am a linux user, I cannot say what exact process is, but I do something called `chmod` to get the file writable. Maybe you know about windows. Try to make the file editable.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe for someone, it will be helpful. The new version of Php-phantomjs(4.*) has no methods:

```
$client->setBinDir('absolute_path/bin');
$client->setPhantomJs('phantomjs.exe');
```

So, instead of it, you can use that:

```
$client->getEngine()->setPath('absolute_path/bin/phantomjs.exe');
```

Comment: to get this to work with Symfony I used the relative path $phantom->getEngine()->setPath('../bin/phantomjs');

Answer (score 3):

FWIW I just installed this on a very quick test project and it worked fine with only one small tweak.

I added the following to my `composer.json` file as per the instructions:

```
"require": {
    "jonnyw/php-phantomjs": "~3.0"
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "PhantomInstaller\\Installer::installPhantomJS"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "PhantomInstaller\\Installer::installPhantomJS"
    ]
}
```

Then `composer install` will install the library and then install phantomjs afterwards.

Then I copied and pasted the top example from http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/usage.html#basic-request into `index.php` (after requiring Composer's autoloader).

All I then had to do (because I'm in the UK) was remove the response status if (as I get a 301) to make the Google homepage show.

Now this was on a Mac but I can't imagine it being any different on Centos.

Then, putting my `index.php` file inside a subdirectory `public`, as you would have in a Laravel install, all I had to do was add the following line after `Client::getInstance()`:

```
$client->setBinDir('../bin');
```

Then it worked again.

Obviously this is not a full Laravel install, but it does mimic the environment alright. One thing I did notice was that changing the `bin-dir` in `composer.json` does not always fully update the files that get put in `bin`. As such, I had to `rm -rf bin vendor` and then `composer update` again to ensure I had a fresh installation of composer and its packages.

Comment: Ok i'll try do the same thing and reinstall it from scratch.

Comment: Maybe first just `rm -rf bin vendor` and then `composer update`. That should give you a fresh Composer installation. But do make sure you have the `bin-dir` thing in `composer.json` as well as setting the `$client`'s bin dir to `../bin`.

Answer (score 3):

The error states

File does not exist or is not executable:

You have shown the file exists. Now make it executable

```
chmod +x /path/to/bin/phantomloader
```

And try again

If this works you need to lock down some of the permissions

What user is php running as ?  When you find out use

```
chmod -x /path/to/bin/phantomloader
chown phpuser  /path/to/bin/phantomloader
chmod u+x  /path/to/bin/phantomloader
```

Check again and it should still work